# Sample application for using flow using wolkenkit

Tags: wolkenkit

Can we get some sample application describing the behaviour of flow mentioned in its documentation.

https://docs.wolkenkit.io/2.0.0/reference/creating-stateful-flows/overview/

A stateful flow is a state machine whose transitions are caused by events. Whenever a stateful flow transitions, it is able to run a reaction, such as sending commands or running tasks. Using their state they have knowledge of their past. This way you can use them to create complex workflows that include conditions and loops, e.g. **to notify a user once an invoice has been rejected for the third time in a row**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good place to start is the [wolkenkit-boards](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-boards) sample application (see a list of all available sample applications [here](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/latest/media/sample-applications/wolkenkit-boards/)). It basically is an application for collaboratively organizing notes, similar to tools such as Trello.

It contains a [tip of the day](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-boards/blob/3237295ee1e1c288e3584b90c854be2aa8d68d95/server/flows/tipOfTheDay.js) workflow, which actually uses a stateful flow under the hoods.

I hope this helps

Comment: I tried to use wolkenkit-boards. I also setup an account on auth0 as described. When I use my own key, after filling username and password, It  takes me back on login screen again and again. When I  do not pass env variable - AUTH_IDENTITY_PROVIDER_URL and AUTH_CLIENT_ID then client side app assumes default credentials commited in source code. But in that case there is no signup option and we do not know username and password to login

Comment: Again, since this is a new problem: Can you please turn this into a question of its own?